# Combining these two Javascript codes

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to combine these two codes to be able to opt-in to two of my campaign lists at the same time. But I have not been able to. Whenever I try either one or the other will receive my opt-in, but not both. Please help me with this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=624607"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=624609"></script>
```

Different combinations I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=624607, http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=624609"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=624607", "http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=624609"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src={"http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=624607, http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=624609"}></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src={http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=624607, http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=624609}></script>
```

Comment: It's not you, it's the site you're pulling from.  They probably have a restriction on requests from the same host for different forms.  Otherwise you could add like 500 of those and give their servers a pretty big headache.

Comment: You can't put multiple URLs in the `src` attribute.

Comment: @janfoeh Thanks for all the help. What if I was to use the html code with the css styles turned off? Do you think I would need a programmer to be able to go in there and change the coding to be able to opt in then. As I'm trying to test on my account first before a friend and I create a product together which the people who opt in will receive, but we both want the leads to be able to follow up and be able to provide value separately.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can do on your own; it's something GetResponse must support in order for this for work. Also as @Barmar said, you cannot add multiple URLs to a single `<script>` tag.

From a short glance at the GetResponse FAQs, it does not seem that they do support what you are trying to achieve. Contact their support to be sure.